# Add class to every link created by plugin

Tags: wordpress, class, plugins

I would like to add class to every link added by all plugins except my must use plugin. Most of them are added by shortcodes and javascript so they are not in DOM and I can't change them.

Thanks ^^

Comment: In fact, if I could wrap all the shortcodes output it would be great : with a class on a div wrapping shortcode output it would be possible for me to detect all a tag.

Comment: Can you please be more specific , what you want exactly ?

Comment: Well : I got a certain style on my <a> tag (with background and linear gradient...) and I apply this css to every <a> tag. The only way for me to not apply this style is to add a class named "no-lnk".
So, if I got a normal link, I don't set no-lnk class. If I got an image link for example, I set no-lnk class.
But the problem is for all the links that are created by plugins : I got one witch use a shortcode, and create links for buttons (Gwolle Guestbook) : I want to desactivate my style on these <a> buton, so the last thing I thought was to detect every shortcode, and wrap it in a div...